# How to use Or and Not java regex operatoers

Tags: java, regex

Requirement:

I have to find a application called **uninstaller** under a directory, that directory contains few files like **Uninstaller**(incase of linux os )**Uninstaller.exe**(in case of windows), **Uninstaller.jar** and **Uninstaller.lax**

I tried

```
final String pattern = "Uninstaller.*.(exe|[^lax]|[^jar])";
final FileFilter filter = new RegexFileFilter(pattern);
files = installDir.listFiles(filter);
```

but its returning Uninstaller.lax in case of linux!

please help me overcome the isssue.

Comment: it is really not clear what you want. Try "Uninstaller(\.bin|\.lax|\.jar)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to match all Unistaller files that end with `bin`, `jar`, or `lax`. In that case, use this:

```
"Uninstaller\.(bin|jar|lax)"
```

**Edit**:

Ah, in that case, you can just match:

```
"^Uninstaller(\.exe)?$"
```

Comment: No, just I want application which is either **Uninstaller** or **Uninstaller.exe**

Comment: @kgopi The `$` matches the end of the line. It makes sure that you don't match anything after `Uninstaller` or `Uninstaller.exe`, such as `Uninstaller.exe.tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

`[^lax]`

You define a character class - a token that matches ANY character as long as it is not l, a, x.

So this token

`(exe|[^lax]|[^jar])`

means

'match exe OR match any character that is not l/a/x OR match any character that is not j/a/r'

Clearly this is not what you want :)

You only want to match `Uninstaller` and `Uninstaller.exe`. So try

`Uninstaller(\.exe)?$`

(the $ means that the string must end)

In this case you don't have to explicitly say all the things you don't want to match, just the things you do.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is `Uninstaller` or `Uninstaller.exe`, then you can use:

```
final String pattern = "Uninstaller(\.exe|$)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex like

```
final String pattern = "Uninstaller(\\.exe)?";
```